# Function to return menu choice; Switch Statement for project

Tags: c#, function, switch-statement

I have to make a function to return the menu option that is selected and then a `switch` statement to show which key is pressed, but I have problems at the function part.

```
class Program
{   
    static void displayMainMenu()
    {
        string title = "Old Yeller Pet Store";
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth /2) + (title.Length / 2 )) + "}", title));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        title = "Main Menu";
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth /2) + (title.Length / 2 )) + "}", title));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        string line = "1.    Buy a Pet";
        Console.WriteLine(line.PadLeft(line.Length+1 + 50));

        string line2 = "2.    Buy Food";
        Console.WriteLine(line2.PadLeft(line2.Length+1 + 50));

        string line3 = "3.    File OPs";
        Console.WriteLine(line3.PadLeft(line3.Length+1 + 50));

        string line4 = "4.    Manager";
        Console.WriteLine(line4.PadLeft(line4.Length+1 + 50));

        string line5 = "5.    Quit";
        Console.WriteLine(line5.PadLeft(line5.Length+1 + 50));
    }

    static void getChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please input which option you choose to use");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        displayMainMenu();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is modify the getChoice method to return a string which will be the selected option. And within the getChoice method write a Console.ReadLine and put the value into a variable and return the variable. This way you call the function getChoice after the displayMenu one and get the value.

I would provide the code myself but since this is more of a homework, I think it will be better for you to understand this and try to do it yourself with this idea :)!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Consider that Console.ReadKey() will wait until you hit a key to continue. After you do, the property Console.ReadKey().Key will contain the value of the key pressed
So, in that case...

```
var key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
switch (key) {
    case ConsoleKey.D1:
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed 1");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D2:
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed 2");
        break;
    //etc...//
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed something else");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I feel like this is progress but I could be wrong? Would the Switch statement replace the If statement in my getChoice function?

```
class Program
{   
    static void displayMainMenu()
    {
        string title = "Old Yeller Pet Store";
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth /2) + (title.Length / 2 )) + "}", title));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        title = "Main Menu";
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth /2) + (title.Length / 2 )) + "}", title));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        string line = "1.    Buy a Pet";
        Console.WriteLine(line.PadLeft(line.Length+1 + 50));

        string line2 = "2.    Buy Food";
        Console.WriteLine(line2.PadLeft(line2.Length+1 + 50));

        string line3 = "3.    File OPs";
        Console.WriteLine(line3.PadLeft(line3.Length+1 + 50));

        string line4 = "4.    Manager";
        Console.WriteLine(line4.PadLeft(line4.Length+1 + 50));

        string line5 = "5.    Quit";
        Console.WriteLine(line5.PadLeft(line5.Length+1 + 50));


    }

    static void getChoice()
    {
        string option;
        int choice;
        Console.WriteLine("Please input which number option you choose to use");
        option = Console.ReadLine();
        choice = Convert.ToInt32(option);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("Lipsum");
            //code to open Buy a Pet menu
        }



    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        displayMainMenu ();
        getChoice();



        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```